# PHP changing query when checkbox is check

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to change a part of a query (the part is 'AND meerdere = $postdata') when a checkbox is clicked. If the checkbox is checked, meerdere should be 1 else it should be 0. standard value should be 0 (if checkbox has not been clicked)

I thought I could do this by using ajax to post the value to the same page. I am trying this in the function checkchanged() But it is not working. When I look on the network tab in the browser, I can see the post 'request' with the data. But the postdata variable stays 0 for my query.   Could any1 help me.

Or am I doing this completely wrong ?  Still a beginner, so you can point out all my faults :)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["postdata"])){
    $postdata = $_POST["postdata"];
    }
else {$postdata='0';} 

$link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","******","******","secretariaat");
        if (!$link) {
            echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
            echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
            echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

$query = "SELECT * FROM wifi WHERE vervaldatum >= CURDATE() AND gebruikt = '0' AND meerdere = $postdata LIMIT 1;";
if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
/* fetch associative array */


  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo"<button value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["code"]."</button>";
      $data = $row["id"];
  }

  /* free result set */
  $result->free();
}   

  mysqli_close($link);
?>


</label>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var postid = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;

        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'processwifi.php',
                    data:{'postid': postid}, 
            success: function(response){
                    location.reload();
                    }
                    });
        });
    });

    function checkchanged(){

        if(document.getElementById("togBtn").checked == true){
            var self = this;
            self.postdata = 1;
        }
        else{
            var self = this;
            self.postdata = 0;
        }
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'wificode.php',
                    data:{'postdata': postdata}, 
            success: function(response){
                    alert('postdata');
                   //location.reload();
                    }
                    });
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that `postdata` is `undefined` in your ajax request. Tried adding `self.postdata` in `data` item of your ajax request?

Comment: The data is being posted. I can see that with inspect element --> network tab in google. So my guess is the ajax request is OK (but could be wrong ofc)

Comment: my bad, it should indeed be self.postdata. did not solve the problem, but you are correct on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a checkbox it returns their value so, in case of:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
```

It will return Bike when submit, using the method defined at the form.

Full example:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

if you check the checkbox, the behaviour will be:

```
$_POST['vehicle'] == "Bike"
```

Now, attending your issue, your checkbox must be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="postdata" value="1"> checkbox text <br>
```

this is only for being strict and for educational purposes.
Now to solve your issue, and following with the example, on PHP, if you only want a 1 not regarding on the value of the checkbox you simply can:

```
if(!isset($_POST['postdata'])) $postdata = 0;
else $postdata = 1;
```

Differences with your code:

```
//check if the value of an input with name="postdata" has been sent
if(isset($_POST["postdata"])){
    //if true, you assign the checkbox value to a var called $postdata
    $postdata = $_POST["postdata"];
  //if not, you assign a String 0 to $postData.
} else {$postdata='0';}
```

** EDIT **
As @DomenikReitzner pointed out, you are assigning the 1 or 0 value to an attribute called postdata of self instead on writing the value on postdata (which is the var you're sending). So, in your ajax code:

```
self.postdata = 1;
// or
self.postdata = 0;
```

should be:

```
postdata = 1;
// or
postdata = 0;
```

But the best option to deal with is the last he posted:

```
const postdata = document.getElementById("togBtn").checked ? 1 : 0;
```

Remember that, for the mysql db engine isn't the same "1" than 1, or "0" than 0 and could cause issues (you're threating it as string or as integer on your database? If you've declared as boolean on it you should use true/false instead of 1/0).

There are various errors, read the answers, write notes in a paper and refactor it understanding what are you doing. Not simply copy-pasting and check.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: You left out the ajax part of the example. He doesn't trigger a form submit.

Comment: cuz i thing the issue isn't on ajax. Moreover is not relevant due to Ajax performs a POST too. i think that the value of $_POST['postdata'] isn't the 1 that he's expecting.

Comment: By the other hand, for the DB engine is not the same "1" than 1, same with 0 and "0" so it's probably the issue. The rest seems to be fine at first sight.

Comment: Yes, it is not, because he doesn't set it correctly in the $.ajax call.

Comment: And postdata will be always set, but it will be always empty.

Comment: true, there's a self that doesn't have nothing to do on there.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner Edited

Comment: @DomenikReitzner this is why i mentioned you to keep a full answer in one single.

Comment: Thank you DomenikReitzner and @JoelBonetR. Ended up solving the  problem in a completely different way, but i learned alot from the info you gave.  ( which is sometimes even beter than actually solving the problem I guess )

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wifi WHERE vervaldatum >= CURDATE() AND gebruikt = '0' AND meerdere = $postdata LIMIT 1;";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wifi WHERE vervaldatum >= CURDATE() AND gebruikt = '0' AND meerdere = ".$postdata." LIMIT 1;";
```

Not sure if this would resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this does not help. It should also work how I wrote it (used it in another part of my project). The real problem is, the value of $postdata does not change from 0 to 1

Comment: yeah. can you check the value of your $_POST['postdata'] with checked and without checked if they have values.

Comment: I get no error message. But $postdata just always has the value 0.

Comment: if the value of $_POST["postdata"] is always zero then something to do with your Ajax call and not php. check the value of postdata from your front end.

Comment: Please don't advise stuff that is still highly vulnerable

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
if(document.getElementById("togBtn").checked == true){
    var self = this;
    self.postdata = 1;
}
else{
    var self = this;
    self.postdata = 0;
}
```

to

```
let postdata = 0;
if(document.getElementById("togBtn").checked == true){
    postdata = 1;
}
```

or

```
const postdata = document.getElementById("togBtn").checked ? 1 : 0;
```

then you can use the variable in your $.ajax request